# Instagram as additional module vs review on busy production

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have an existing website on production with real users. I added Instagram functionality on development. 
I can’t deploy changes on production without working part of the application and wait for approval. And what if they don’t approve it?

Quoted from [Permissions Review](https://www.instagram.com/developer/review/):

> **App development phase**: We only review final and production version
>   apps. Submissions with test and development version apps will not be
>   approved.

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: what permissions are you requesting, does it fall in an approved usecase?

Comment: Make a screencast in your development environment and submit along with like to website, I think they just want to know its a legit website or app your are working on.

Comment: @krisrak Sorry for answering now. Time zones...
Basically, "first type" user can register on website using Instagram and see his/her media list. 
Second type user can see "first type's" user number of likes and comments.

That's it.

What permissions do you think I will require? 
public_content, basic?, likes?, comments?

Comment: you said u already have a website, without instagram what does it do?, you will need `basic` and `public_content`

Comment: @krisrak thanks for your help. We submitted with those two and we will see how it goes.